# Active-Passive IIS Infrastructure

Tags: windows, iis, architecture, operating-system, sysinternals

We are trying to create an IIS infrastructure. Because of the application's infrastructures (they are many types of applications from old school to SPA) we thought that Active-Passive infrastructure will be more appopriate.

So this brings an other question that is there any limitation of IIS exists as request count? Or it can be managed by adding cpu and ram as required? Also the incoming request counts can be monitored from IIS machine within a tool some kind of ProcessExplorer (from sysinternals) to act proactively on hardware expanding? (adding more CPU,RAM etc.)

Comment: Most web apps on IIS should be deployed in load balancing clusters, not active-passive. You cannot put too many questions in a single post and need more focus.

Comment: @LexLi I know in normal conditions it should be like that but the applications are using session data, there is no redis or smth so if i use load balancing clusters then i will unable to use operations with sessions. Wegihted Round Robin can be thought as an alternative but it is almost same thing as active-passive. That's why i asked this question.

Comment: @CanYıldırmaz as Lex li said for your scenario load balancing is the suitable option, you can use iis ARR load balancer, reverse proxy, and network load balancer. Application Request Routing provides a client affinity feature that maps a client to a content server behind Application Request Routing for the duration of a client session. When this feature is enabled, the load balancing algorithm is applied only for the very first request from the client.

Comment: You can also use an Nginx load balancer. It can be configured with a sticky session option.